# Python: AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'add'. (operator module)

Tags: python

I am currently trying to finish a task that goes towards my GCSE (exam). The task is to make a program that generates 3 random multiply, add and subtract questions. However while the program is trying to pick a random operator it displays the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python stuff/GCSE.py", line 8, in <module>
    operators=[operator.add, operator.sub, operator.mul]
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'add'
```

Here's my code:

```
import random
import operator
user_name=input("What's your name?")
print("Hello " + user_name + "\nRULE:\nEnter your answers as integers.")
for x in range(0,10):
    number1=random.randint(0,10)
    number2=random.randint(0,10)
    operators=[operator.add, operator.sub, operator.mul]
    operator=random.choice(operators)
    print(number1, operator, number2)
```

Comment: Your traceback mentions `operator.plus`, but your code uses `operator.add`. Please provide up-to-date versions of both traceback and code, and make sure they coincide.

Comment: Oh sorry didn't notice that, thanks.

Comment: `operator` **does** have an `add` (assuming you're `import`ing the correct file), but not a `plus`. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.add). What does `operator.__file__` show you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overshadow operator module in first iteration in line:

```
operator=random.choice(operators)
```

Assign non-conflicting name (e.g. op). By doing so, in second iteration `operator` would still point to the module.